# Python - Slicing an array of unknown dimension by a fixed pad

Tags: python-3.x

Given a random array, I wish to remove a pad of 10 pixels from each side, what's the best way to do this without hard-coding if-else statements?

```
my_array = np.ones([3, 250, 250, 250, 1])
n_dims = len(my_array) - 2
if n_dims == 2:
    my_array = [:, 10:-10, 10:-10, :]
elif n_dims == 3: # my_array triggers this in this particular instance
    my_array = [:, 10:-10, 10:-10, 10:-10, :]
elif n_dims == 4:
    my_array = [:, 10:-10, 10:-10, 10:-10, 10:-10, :]
elif n_dims == 5:
    my_array = [:, 10:-10, 10:-10, 10:-10, 10:-10, 10:-10, :]
```

Looking for a smart way about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in `slice` to create a variable list of slices:

```py
import numpy as np

my_array = np.ones([3, 250, 250, 250, 1])
n_dims = my_array.ndim - 2  # get proper dimensions

slices = [slice(10,-10)]*n_dims

my_array = my_array[:, *slices, :]

print(my_array.shape)
```

Output:

```py
(3, 230, 230, 230, 1)
```